# Function to determine values matching a specific frequency in an array using for loops c++

Tags: c++, arrays, function, for-loop, frequency

Apologies in advance for any obvious mistakes, I am not very skilled when it comes to programming. I am writing a program to determine the number of values in an array that occur at the exact frequency the user searches. For example, if the data set contains the numbers 5,6,6,7,7,8,9,9 and the user searches the array for a frequency of 2, because the numbers 6,7, and 9 all appear exactly 2 times, they match the frequency of 2, therefor the program would output that there are 3 numbers in the array that match the frequency of 2, and would list all of the values matching the frequency one time. Below is the function from my program that is supposed to perform this calculation but each time I run the program I get a value of 0 for values matching the frequency when there should be values appearing. The two for loops are a requirement for my function so I need those to work correctly as opposed to using a different method. I believe that some loops may need to be included inside others but I can't quite get it to fit. Any help fixing this function would be very appreciated.

```
short countOfFrequency (long data[], short dsize, long FreqNumbers[ ], short 
Frequency)
{

short i, j;
short count = 0;
short Value;

/*search above loop
(loop searches above each element in the array, if an element of the same 
value is found above the element, the loop terminates)*/ 
for (i=0; i<dsize; i++)
{
    Value = data[i]; //the variable 'Value' is assigned to each element
    for (j=0; j<i; j++)
    {
        break;
    }
}

/*search below + count loop
(loop searches below each element in the array, if an element is found with 
the same value, the variable 'count' is increased by one)*/
for (j=i+1; j<dsize; j++)
{
    if (Value==data[i])
    {
        count++;
    }   
}

/*(If the count of a value matches the users desired frequency, that value
is stored in the FreqNumbers array)*/ 
if (count==Frequency)
    {
        FreqNumbers[dsize++] = Value;
    }

return FreqNumbers[dsize];
}
```

Comment: Could you explain what you're trying to do in your code? It'd make it easier to understand perhaps.

Comment: @Ashutosh I've added some comments in the code that'll hopefully make it easier to follow, sorry about that.

Comment: Are you guaranteed that the numbers in the array will already be in sorted order (lowest to highest)? Or if not, are you allowed to sort? And, do you envision `FreqNumbers` holding the values that matched the requested frequency number when you are done?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin The numbers in the array are not guaranteed to be sorted, though I would say they are allowed to be sorted. And yes, I would like the values matching the requested frequency to be stored in `FreqNumbers` and then returned and displayed via another function in the program.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should use vector instead of an array.
Second, you should pass FreqNumbers as a reference if you want to get a list of numbers.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<vector>
#include<map>

void countOfFrequency(std::vector<long> &data, std::vector<long> &FreqNumbers, short Frequency)
{
    short count = 0;
    short Value;
    int dsize = data.size();
    std::map<long, long > mapFreq; // first: for store each value of vector data, second for store it's counter
    mapFreq.insert(std::pair<long, long>(data[0], 1));
    for(int i = 1; i < dsize; i++)
    {
        auto &it = mapFreq.find(data[i]);
        if(it != mapFreq.end())
        {
            it->second++;
        }
        else
        {
            mapFreq.insert(std::pair<long, long>(data[i], 1));
        }
    }
    for(auto it : mapFreq)
    {
        if(it.second == Frequency)
            FreqNumbers.push_back(it.first);
    }
}


int main()
{
    std::vector<long> data = { 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 9, 9 };
    std::vector<long> FreqNumbers;
    countOfFrequency(data, FreqNumbers, 2);
    if(FreqNumbers.size())
    {
        for(auto number : FreqNumbers)
        {
            std::cout << number << ", ";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on how much of the niceties of C++ you can use. Given your existing code, there is nothing unique to C++ being used. That may be as your instructor intends it at this stage of your class. If that is the case, then a simple manual sort routine and then a call to a function passing your data, the size of the data, an equally sized array to hold values that match the requested frequency and the frequency to find is about as basic as you can get. e.g.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int countfreq (int *data, int dsize, int *freqvals, int freq)
{
    int last = *data,   /* set last to first value in data */
        idx = 0,        /* index for freqvals to return */
        seq = 1;        /* sequential values count */

    if (freq <= 0 || freq > dsize)  /* is requested freq valid? */
        return 0;

    for (int i = 1; i < dsize; i++) {   /* loop 2nd value to end */
        if (last == data[i])            /* if last == current */
            seq++;                      /* increment sequential count */
        else {  /* otherwise */
            if (seq == freq)            /* sequential count == freq? */
                freqvals[idx++] = last; /* add last value to freqvals */
            seq = 1;                    /* reset sequential count 1 */
        }
        last = data[i];                 /* set last = current */
    }
    if (seq == freq)                    /* handle last value in data */
        freqvals[idx++] = last;

    return idx;     /* return freqvals index */
}

/* simple insertion sort */
void inssort (int *arr, int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        for (int j = i - 1; j >= 0; j--)
            if (arr[j] > arr[j + 1]) {
                int tmp = arr[j];
                arr[j] = arr[j + 1];
                arr[j + 1] = tmp;
            }
            else
                break;
}

int main (void) {

    int data[] = { 8, 9, 5, 6, 7, 6, 7, 9 },    /* unsorted data */
        dsize  = sizeof data / sizeof *data,    /* number of elements */
        *freqvals = new int[dsize],             /* allocate for freqvals */
        freq  = 0,      /* frequency from user  */
        nfreq = 0;      /* return from function */

    for (int i = 0; i < dsize; i++)         /* zero the freqvals array */
        freqvals[i] = 0;

    inssort (data, dsize);                  /* sort data */

    cout << "enter requested frequency: ";  /* prompt for frequency input */
    if (!(cin >> freq)) {
        cerr << "error: invalid input.\n";
        return 1;
    }

    /* call function saving return in nfreq */
    if ((nfreq = countfreq (data, dsize, freqvals, freq))) {
        cout << "the values matching requested frequency were: ";
        for (int i = 0; i < nfreq; i++)     /* output csv */
            if (i)
                cout << ", " << freqvals[i];
            else
                cout << freqvals[i];
        cout << "\n";
    }
    else    /* otherwise, no values matched requested frequency */
        cout << "no values appear with the requested frequency.\n";

    delete[] freqvals;  /* free allocated memory */
}
```

There is nothing inherently C++ about the solution aside from using `cin/cout` and `new/delete`, which could just as well have been `fgets/printf` and `malloc/free` with `stdio.h` and `stdlib.h` used instead of `iostream`.

If you do have the ability to use a `vector` for your array, then you can make use of the niceties that C++ provides. You can simply `sort` your vector and simplify the function parameters by passing only a constant reference to your `data` vector and the frequency to find. You can return a vector from your function and then simply test the `.size()` of the returned vector to determine if any values with the requested frequency were found. The logic is identical, the tools you have to work with are a bit more convenient, e.g.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

vector<int> countfreq (vector<int>& data, int freq)
{
    vector<int> freqvals;       /* vector to return */
    int dsize = data.size(),    /* size of initial check */
        last = data.front(),    /* first value in data */
        count = 0,              /* count flag for range loop */
        seq = 1;                /* sequential values counted */

    if (freq <= 0 || freq > dsize)  /* is freq valid? */
        return freqvals;

    for (auto& i : data) {      /* loop over data */
        if (!count) {           /* if first iter, set flag continue */
            count++;
            continue;
        }
        if (last == i)          /* if current equals last */
            seq++;              /* increment sequential count */
        else {  /* otherwise */
            if (seq == freq)    /* if sequential count == freq */
                freqvals.push_back(last);   /* add value to vector */
            seq = 1;            /* reset sequential count = 1 */
        }
        last = i;               /* update last */
    }
    if (seq == freq)            /* handle last value in data */
        freqvals.push_back(last);

    return freqvals;            /* return vector */
}

int main (void) {

    vector<int> data = { 8, 9, 5, 6, 7, 6, 7, 9 };  /* unsorted data */
    int freq;   /* the frequency of values to find */

    sort (data.begin(), data.end());    /* sort data */

    cout << "enter requested frequency: ";  /* prompt for freq input */
    if (!(cin >> freq)) {
        cerr << "error: invalid input.\n";
        return 1;
    }

    vector<int> frequency = countfreq (data, freq); /* call function */
    if (frequency.size()) {             /* does return have elements? */
        int count = 0;                  /* flag for output control */
        cout << "the values matching requested frequency were: ";
        for (auto& i : frequency)       /* loop over values in return */
            if (count)
                cout << ", " << i;      /* output as csv */
            else {
                cout << i;
                count = 1;
            }
        cout << "\n";
    }
    else    /* otherwise, handle no values returned */
        cout << "no values appear with the requested frequency.\n";

}
```

(**note:** the values you provided were used in unsorted order for the contents of `data`)

Regardless which you make use of, the output will be the same, e.g.

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/frequency
enter requested frequency: 0
no values appear with the requested frequency.

$ ./bin/frequency
enter requested frequency: 1
the values matching requested frequency were: 5, 8

$ ./bin/frequency
enter requested frequency: 2
the values matching requested frequency were: 6, 7, 9

$ ./bin/frequency
enter requested frequency: 3
no values appear with the requested frequency.
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions. There are many ways to go about this, so do not think your are limited to just this approach. You are free to put the pieces of the puzzle together however you wish.

Comment: We have not yet covered `vector` in class, but the first solution works great. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Sure, glad to help. There is always more that one way to skin-the-cat with C/C++. Good luck with your coding. (don't forget to select the answer as answering your question if it was helpful, if not, select some other answer, but select one so this question doesn't continue to bounce around in the unanswered queue)